# Symfony2 Set form data to Auth User Class

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony

Im use this form code;

```
public function accountAction(Request $request)
    {                   
        $user = $this->getUser();
        $account_form = $this->createForm(new SettingAccountForm(), $user);

        $account_form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($account_form->isValid()) 
        {           
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->flush();
        }

        return new Response("ok");
    }
```

When submitted the form, i cant user data beacuse form data is appointed. What should i do? When validated should be appoint.

Comment: Questions: Is ::getUser() a function you provide or do you expect the controller to provide it for you?

Comment: What do you mean by "appointed"